# Audio tag doesn't work in Cordova web app if the mp3 file comes from port 8443

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, audio

I developed a Cordova SPA app and I would like to play mp3 by using an audio tag. My mp3 files are under a 8443 port (from Tomcat server), and I tried: if files come from port 80 or port 443 it works, when the file comes from port 8443 it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I debugging audio tag with chrome inspector and I verified that when file comes from 8443 attributes duration=NaN and currentTime=0, when file comes from 443 duration = 215.428 and currentTime=2.342024 and in this case it works. But I don't know what to do.

Comment: I add another track: I receive this error from Android logcat: 08-06 10:11:34.887    8916-8963/it.etc.etcware E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Error configuring data source: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
08-06 10:11:34.887    8916-8963/it.etc.etcware E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Unable to configure metadata extractor

Answer (score 0):

I solved redirecting 8443 port to 443. I suppose this was a Chromium problem (that is the Cordova embedded browser) that is not able to manage URL with 8443 port. I opened an issue to Chromium.